# PagerSettings and Globalization

Tags: c#, asp.net, globalization

I have a gridview called `pnlGrid` and a PagerSettings inside of it.

I've tried to create a `meta:resourceKey` but it produces the error:

```
Error Creating Control: The 'PagerSettings' can't have a meta:resourceKey attibute.
```

I've searched a lot but still can't find how to globalize the `PagerSettings` or access it in the code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this url: http://codeverge.com/asp.net.localization/localisation-of-a-gridview-control-probl/853

Try putting the meta:resourcekey on the GridView itself, and then refer to the subproperties in the key:

GridViewResource1.PagerSettings.Whatever --> "Whatever"